# Run FORMAT command from task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I'm trying to get a scheduled Format running on Win10.

I have a Batch File that consists of the following line:

```
Format F: /V:test /Q /FS:NTFS /A:4096
```

Starting the Batch manually Formats the drive as desired, but starting the Batch as a Scheduled Task gives me an error:

> cannot open volume for direct access.

I did a lot of Google Research but nobody seems to have found a solution or hasn't shared one.

I already did try/ensured the following things:

- The Task runs with highest privileges
- The user has admin rights and full Control over the Folder
- I tried running it from SYSTEM - didn't work
- The Task is configured for Win10 and running only as user is logged on

Comment: why do you need to format a drive again and again?

Comment: Is the batch script located on `F:`, or is `F:` the working directory?

Comment: @aschipfl The batch script is located in C:/sompath/folder. F: is the working directory.

Comment: You mention that you are able to run it manually, while it is located on your C:-drive and F: is the working directory. Do you mean that you open a command prompt on the F:-drive, and from there you launch the command `C:\sompath\folder\whatever.bar`? Or how exactly do you run the batchfile manually?